# Transparent ViewController

Tags: ios, uiviewcontroller

I'm pushing a UIViewController with

```
[otherController presentViewController: newController animated: NO completion: nil];
```

Then nib for newController has the base view, a smaller view and a text field and some buttons in the smaller view. I want the base view to be transparent gray, so I can see the view of the view controller beneath it, while making it obvious to the user that that other view is disabled.

I've tried setting the Alpha value low (which alpha-ed my other controls), setting the view background to a transparent black, and unsetting the Opaque flag. None of those work. I just get an opaque light gray background.

Here's my view controller:

```
@interface MyEditQueryViewController : UIViewController

@property (nonatomic, strong) id<MyEditQueryDelegate> delegate;
@property (nonatomic, strong) IBOutlet UITextField* textField;
@property (nonatomic, strong) IBOutlet UIView* editView;
@property (nonatomic, strong) IBOutlet UIButton* cancelButton;
@property (nonatomic, strong) IBOutlet UIButton* saveButton;
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSString* defaultText;
@property (nonatomic) CGFloat verticalOffset;

- (id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil;
- (id)initWithDefaultText:(NSString*)defaultText orign:(CGPoint)origin;

- (IBAction)cancelTapped:(id)sender;
- (IBAction)saveTapped:(id)sender;
@end
```

Is there a way to make that view translucent?

Answer (score 1):

On `iPhone`, the only way to accomplish this (outside of `UIAlertView` and `UIActionSheet`) is by presenting a `UIView` as a subview on the `UIViewController` that will serve as the background view.  The `UIView` you present can take up the full screen and use a transparent/translucent view for most of it's view to accomplish the dimming effect.

---

On `iPad`, in addition to `UIAlertView` and `UIActionSheet`, you can also modally present views that are not full screen.  These have their own view controllers.  To do this, you need to set the `UIModalPresentationStyle` to one of the following:

- `UIModalPresentationPageSheet`
- `UIModalPresentationFormSheet`

However, both of these options are a little limiting (in my opinion) in terms of how you can size them and where you can place them, so if you want full customization, you'll have to do it the same way I explained for iPhone, by presenting a separate `UIView` on the `UIViewController` that serves as the background view.

---

Other than the `UIModalPresentationPageSheet` and `UIModalPresentationFormSheet` options for the iPad, setting a transparent/translucent background for a view controller will assume a white background behind the back-most layer you can set the color of.

---

It should also be noted that `UIAlertView` and `UIActionSheet` are intended (by Apple) to be used as is and should not be subclassed, whereas you can subclass `UIView` all you want to get whatever look you desire.

Comment: Are you saying a UIView in addition to the one that the UIViewController has by default?

Comment: Yes.  Add a subview to the `UIViewController`'s `view`.

Comment: In the nib, I added a view under "View" with Alpha: 0.5 and a black background, but I still don't see the contents of the other view controller. It's all gray.

Comment: I did. Unless you're trying to say something other that what you said, it doesn't work.

Comment: @kwiqsilver - I don't use this approach myself, however are you sure it doesn't work? I've seen this method as an accepted answer before.

Comment: The fact that you're referring to "the other view controller" tells me you're not reading my answer correctly.  You should have only one view controller.

Comment: @JasperBlues At work, I'm using an approach similar to what you're answer explains... and mainly doing it because I need the same view across several other view controllers, but my answer provides the most basic implementation of the effect kwiqsilver is going for.

Comment: @nhgrif Good answer. Only one crit: I wouldn't say it's the 'only' way.

Answer (score 0):

This kind of thing is easy when using a custom RootViewController to manage its own container views. The root view controller can then define its own navigation system or delegate to a standard UIKit component.

This also has the advantage of being able to use *domain-specific* language - method names that model your specific app in the Root VC's interface - for example [rootViewController presentMenuItem:menuItem].

I have an example of an app using a root view controller [here](http://www.github.com/typhoon-framework/Typhoon-example).

And here's another code snippet (from another app) that presents an overlay with a semi-transparent background:

```
- (void)presentOverlayViewController:(UIViewController*)viewController
{
    LogDebug(@"Presenting overlay view controller: %@", viewController);
    if (_overlayViewController)
    {
        [self dismissOverlayViewController];
    }

    [self.view setUserInteractionEnabled:NO];
    [self.view bringSubviewToFront:_tintView];
    [_tintView setAlpha:0.0];
    [self.view bringSubviewToFront:_overlayViewContainer];
    _overlayViewController = viewController;

    CGSize screenSize = [[UIScreen mainScreen] currentSize];

    [viewController willMoveToParentViewController:self];
    [_overlayViewContainer addSubview:viewController.view];
    [_overlayViewController.view setPosition:(CGPoint) {(screenSize.width / 2) - (_overlayViewController.view.frame.size.width / 2),
            (screenSize.height / 2) - (_overlayViewController.view.frame.size.height / 2)}];

    __weak UIView* overlayViewContainer = _overlayViewContainer;
    __weak UIView* view = self.view;
    __weak UIView* tintView = _tintView;
    [UIView transitionWithView:self.view duration:0.60 options:UIViewAnimationOptionCurveEaseInOut animations:^
    {
        [tintView setAlpha:0.7];
        CGRect newFrame = overlayViewContainer.frame;
        newFrame.origin.y -= screenSize.height;
        [overlayViewContainer setUserInteractionEnabled:YES];
        overlayViewContainer.frame = newFrame;
    } completion:^(BOOL complete)
    {
        [viewController didMoveToParentViewController:self];
        [view setUserInteractionEnabled:YES];
    }];
}
```

This approach will work on either iOS or iPad, and can in fact be written to work on both.

**Edit:**

If you haven't got a custom root view controller set right down as the rootVC on UIWindow, you can still do this by adding the same methods on the VC that will be presenting the semi-transparent overlay.

**Edit2:**

Please note the addition of:

```
 [viewController willMoveToParentViewController:self];
 [viewController didMoveToParentViewController:self];
```

. . which are required, as pointed out by Jesse Rusak

Comment: That makes sense, but you need to use the UIViewController containment APIs rather than just grabbing the view out of the view controller.

Comment: Yes, also rotation, view unloading, event handling etc, will all break or be a pain in surprising cases. It's basically unsupported to do this pre-iOS 5, so it would be nice to at least call out the "right" way to do this with those APIs.

Comment: Sub views are supported, but not sub views that are part of a different view controller.

Comment: @JesseRusak Wow - I didn't know that this was specifically unsupported pre IOS5. I just thought it was more work. . . In fact, even used that same approach pre-iOS5! Anyway - thanks for the tip.

Comment: The most official docs I can find are from Apple's UIViewController docs: "Your container view controller must associate a child view controller with itself before adding the child’s root view to the view hierarchy." I'm sure there's something in a WWDC video somewhere... :)